# div with gridview border-left collapse

Tags: html, css, asp.net, gridview

I've a GridView in a scrollable div:

```
<div style="overflow:auto;height:500px;border:1px solid #c1c1c1; border-collapse:collapse">
    <asp:GridView ID="gridID" BorderStyle="None" runat="server" style="margin:0px;" GridLines="None" Width="100%" CssClass="cssGrid">
        (...)
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

That's rendered like:

```
<div style="overflow: auto;height:500px;border-collapse:collapse">   
    <div>
        <table class="cssGrid" id="ctl00_MainContent_gridID" style="border-style:None;height:100%;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;margin:0px;" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="CollapsibleRow">
                    <td onclick="collapsible('SezioneUno', 'ctl00_MainContent_gridID')" colspan="13" align="center">SezioneUno</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="SezioneUno" align="center">
                    <td style="width:4%;">
                        <span id="ctl00_MainContent_gdIncongruenti_ctl03_label">142454</span>
                    </td>
                    (...)       
                </tr>
                (...)
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS like this:

```
.cssGrid
{
    width: 99%;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: solid 1px #525252;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.cssGrid td
{
    padding: 2px;
    /*padding-right: 10px;*/
    border: solid 1px #c1c1c1;
    color: #717171;
    max-width : 90px;
    font-size: 8pt;
}
```

And now I've a double border only on the left side, because on the right I've the scrollbar. It's possible to eliminate it? I can't eliminate it directly from the div, because I need at least on the bottom of it or while scrolling the grid seems to be appear from nothing. I can't leave only on the bottom of the div because the grid is partially or totally collapsible, then I need always a box around them.. One solution is to set border-left to 0 on grid td, but how I can do that without css or without adding a new css class that change from the first just for the border-left?

[image]

Same grid when half collapsed (is in a scrollable div):

[image]

I don't want the double border on the left. I want a unique border, like meant to be with border-collapse.. I know I can get it doing border-left: 0px on css on .cssGrid td, but how can I do the same without affect all the cssGrid gridview in the project?

Comment: Hi Frank, can you post a picture of the actual problem? its a little hard to grasp. Thanks.

Comment: Add a rule: `.cssGrid tr td:first-child { border-left: 0px...`

Comment: @abhitalks: .mGrid was a typo.. That rule works great, but I have a lot of grid using that cssClass, but not all of them are in a scrollable div like this. In fact I need that rules is just on two GridView, I had to create another class like cssGrid adding only this new rule? Or ther's another way?

Comment: On those two gridviews add another class say `cssGrid2`. Specify the rule on only that class i.e. `.cssGrid2 tr td:first-child { border-left: 0px... `.

Comment: Thanks! I forget I can assign more than one cssClass to one element..